# Magento API url dispatch via custom admin url

Tags: redirect, custom-admin-url

Can my store resolves API request using custom admin url? Eg: https://admin.magento.lc/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1? Here problem is if I use api url via custom admin url it redirects to frontend.

Comment: Interesting, never tried it with a custom admin subdomain. Did you already solve it?

Comment: not, @AnnaVölkl, it is pending

Comment: @mageUz Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @duke not solved, see answer given below. api is frontend route, so it is not possible working with api via admin url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having a look into `/app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc/config.xml` i saw, that the route is only configured for the `frontend`, not for `admin`:

```
<config>
<modules ...>
<global ...>
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <api>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Api</module>
                    <frontName>api</frontName>
                </args>
            </api>
        </routers>
...
</frontend>
```

So there is no admin-route for `/api` which might be the cause why you get redirected. I did not test it though.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution** is to deactivate the 301 or 302 redirect from `System > Web > Url Options > Auto-redirect to Base URL`

Then try again without custom admin url : http://magento.dev/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/

**This may cause some issues loosing http://example.com/store/ to http://www.example.com/store/ redirections...**

---

**Second solution** is to set a rewrite rule on the web server config (here Apache vhost) :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.magento\.biz$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/
RewriteRule ^ https://magento.biz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```